# How fix "Invalid host header" error in vue 3 project?

Tags: docker, vue.js, deployment, digital-ocean, vuejs3

I'm tring to deploy a simple test app on cloud with digital ocean.
I created a new app with the vue cli (VUE3).
After i dockerized the app and exposed to 8080.
I configured the nginx so that it route traffic from port :80 to :8080 on the container.
Everything is ok, but when i try to visit the page i got this error "Invalid host header".
I searched on google and everybody suggest to create a vue.config.js file with this code:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
     disableHostCheck: true
  } }
```

I tried this solution but nothing is changed. How can i fix this error?
I also read that this kind of solution create vulnerabilities, is there a way to fix without this solution?
Thank you in advance for the response

Answer (score 2):

In your vue.config.js file you can try this settings

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: "all"
    }
})
```

Comment: this gave an error. See Oren Hahiashvili's answer for the proper syntax

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution!**

The mentioned solutions above does not work for me.

I am not sure when the property `allowedHosts` was changed.

currently, we supposed to provide an array to the `allowedHosts` property.

```
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: [
      'yourdomain.com'
    ]
}
```

Just look for the file `vue.config.js`, then replace: `yourdomain.com` with your own personal domain.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Oren Hahiashvili's answer when you don't know ahead of time what hosts will be accessing the devServer (e.g., when testing on multiple environments) is to set `devServer.diableHostCheck` in `vue.config.js`.  For example,

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
};
```

Note this is less secure than Oren Hahiashvili's answer, so only use this when you don't know the hosts, and you still need to serve using devServer.